# Hangfire DisableConcurrentExecution vs Worker Count = 1

Tags: c#, batch-processing, hangfire

What is the difference between `DisableConcurrentExecution` and `Worker Count = 1`?

I set `Worker Count = 1` in my `BackgroundJobServerOptions` but it seems that both jobs executed (only one queue).  What is the point of setting this value if more than one job can run?

Comment: It seems an issue with Hangfire. Same kind of discussion going on here : https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/231 . If possible please post your code so that I can help to suggest code fix to disableconcurrentexecution. Please do remember that DisableConcurrentExecution attribute considers method name and NOT method parameters. If you call same method with different parameters it treats it as calling the same method again and queues it

Comment: Note: there are much more advanced options available in the paid version $1500+ a year https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html

Answer (score 9):

They do essentially the same thing **IF you are only using a single backgroundjob server.**

```
DisableConcurrentExecution
```

This is a per job attribute that ensures that two instances of the class/method name are not running at the same time. This is accomplished by a distributed sql lock if using SQL server backend. A worker will pick the job up and attempt to acquire the lock for the job/method name with the given timeout. Note that the worker process will be "busy" while it is waiting for the SQL lock to open up and will be unable to process other jobs.

```
Worker Count = 1
```

This is a per hangfire backgroundjob server instance setting. If you have a single hangfire backgroundjob processing server, setting this to one essentially causes all your jobs to not run concurrently (only one job processor). If you have two servers running with both having a WorkerCount of 1, your jobs will run concurrently because your total worker pool is 2. The DisableConcurrentExecution attribute will ensure the job does not run concurrently regardless of the number of workers or servers you have activated.

Comment: So what does the timeout mean? If I have a long running task (can range anywhere from 5 min to 1 hour depending on how many items are to be processed), should I set `DisableConcurrentExecution(60 * 60)`?

Comment: It will throw a DistributedLockTimeoutException when the timeout has expired if another job is running. If you don't want exceptions/failed jobs to occur you would need a longer timeout than your longest expected job to run. If you are scheduling your jobs at an interval significantly smaller than 1 hour I'd suggest trying a different approach so you won't  have a bunch a jobs clogging up your queues waiting for the distributed lock to open up.

Comment: So what do you recommend if I want to queue up multiple jobs (most average 15 min, occasionally 1 hour) to run one after another?

Comment: It really depends on what the tasks are doing and why you don't want them to run concurrently. If these are the only tasks you are running and only want them to run one at a time I would probably set your worker count to 1 so that you don't have to worry about the timeout (or do both for forward compatibility).

Comment: It's calling a web service to upload data to a ERP system and their web service does not allow 1 account to upload concurrently.  I've set WorkerCount = 1 but it didn't seem to work.  Question is what happens if I set `DistributedLockTimeoutException(60 * 60)` and the current job is done in 10 minutes.  Does the next job keep trying every min within the Timeout to see if the lock is free or do jobs start every 60 min?

Comment: To anyone who still might be interested in 2021 :-):
When a job is done, the lock gets disposed so other jobs can continue normally.  I saw this in the decompiled code:
`((IDisposable) filterContext.Items["DistributedLock"]).Dispose();`

Comment: Hello guys, I am facing problem when DisableConcurrentExecution attribute decorate with parameterize method. I want to stop concurrent execution of method if parameter is same. Is it possible?

Comment: I posted the question here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469044/hangfire-disableconcurrentexecution-prevent-concurrent-execution-if-same-val
This question gives more details of my code.